# null pointerexception at button onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to capture image from camera view on camera key click even. it was working fine but I want to change UI and use button to click capture, so placed button in main.xml
program shows no error but when I run the program it gives runtime error with nullpointer exception at  line button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(). I checked whether I misspelled button Id name but its the same.
` public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    //make the screen full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //remove the title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mResultView=new ResultView(this);
    mPreview = new Preview(this);

    //set Content View as the preview
    setContentView(mPreview);

    //add result view  to the content View
    addContentView(mResultView,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //set the orientation as landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
    //Button capture_Button = (Button) findViewById(id.button_click);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCameraReadyFlag = false;
            mPreview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });


}`
```

this is my main activity code

```
enter code here

02-11 19:21:58.367: I/Process(5729): Sending signal. PID: 5729 SIG: 9
02-11 19:22:04.987: D/AndroidRuntime(6006): Shutting down VM
02-11 19:22:04.987: W/dalvikvm(6006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ee368.siftexample/com.ee368.siftexample.SIFTExampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at com.ee368.siftexample.SIFTExampleActivity.onCreate(SIFTExampleActivity.java:89)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-11 19:22:04.987: E/AndroidRuntime(6006):     ... 11 more
02-11 19:22:09.097: I/Process(6006): Sending signal. PID: 6006 SIG: 9'
```

this is my log window

and this is xml layout

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can somebody help me solving this error plz? and also how do I use button instead of onkeydown()? thanx in advance

Comment: can you post your xml where this button is added?

Comment: ya, sorry I forget it first now its there .

Comment: @gooner :where is line number 89 in SIFTExampleActivity.java ?

Comment: its is at  'button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {'

Comment: @gooner : if you are using current xml in mResultView class then to get button reference use `button = (Button)mResultView. findViewById(R.id.button_click);`

Comment: yes I tried that but still getting the same error at same line

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mPreview` as your content view instead of your layout.
That is why `findViewById(R.id.button_click);` returns null and you don't handle this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding this layout to your activity :

```
mResultView=new ResultView(this);
mPreview = new Preview(this);

//set Content View as the preview
setContentView(mPreview);

//add result view  to the content View
addContentView(mResultView,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And as you mentioned, "so placed button in `main.xml`".

You can not access view controls of any xml without adding that as a `contentview`.

Comment: how can I add buttons to contentview? can u please suggest me some links or tutorials?
thanx

Comment: @gooner you must have used some view in th e Preview class, so add your button in that view file. By that you can access this button in your activity.